# Sending a packet with nodejs packets

Tags: node.js, tcp

I am using the package:

```
http://bigeasy.github.io/packet
```

On the documentation it says parsing is done by:

```
parser.packet("pkt_id", "x16, l16 => id");
...
parser.parse(buffer);
...
parser.extract("pkt_id", function (packet) {...
```

But how do I serialize data and send it as buffer?
I tried

```
var stuff = serializer("pkt_id", {var1, var2});
socket.write(stuff);
```

But it is just wrong, I can't find it anywhere in the documentation on how to pack data and build it into a buffer and send it to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Buffer` in node thusly:

```
var stuff = serializer("pkt_id", "this should be a string");
socket.write(new Buffer(stuff, 'binary');
```

For more on the `Buffer` global object, check the docs:
http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Comment: Thats because `{ var1, var2 }` is invalid. 1) This isn't correct Javascript syntax 2) The method expects the second argument to be of type string

Comment: I still was not able to make it work, so I moved to another package, which is older. And is kinda harder to use for my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016568/nodejs-add-null-terminated-string-to-buffer