# nodejs add null terminated string to buffer

Tags: node.js

I am trying to replicate a packet.

This packet:

```
2C 00 65 00 03 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 42 4C 41 5A
45 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 42 4C 41 5A 45......
```

`2c 00` is the size of the packet...
`65 00` is the packet id 101...
`03 00` is the number of elements in the array...

Now here comes my problem, `42 4C 41 5A 45` is a string... There are exactly 3 Instances of that string in that packet if it is complete... But my problem is it is not just null terminated it has `00 00 00 00` spaces between those instances.

My code:

```
function channel_list(channels) {
  var packet = new SmartBuffer();

  packet.writeUInt16LE(101); // response packet for list of channels
  packet.writeUInt16LE(channels.length)

  channels.forEach(function (key){
    console.log(key);
    packet.writeStringNT(key);
  });

  packet.writeUInt16LE(packet.length + 2, 0);

  console.log(packet.toBuffer());
}
```

But how do I add the padding?

I am using this package, https://github.com/JoshGlazebrook/smart-buffer/

Comment: Can't you just add a couple `packet.writeInt16(0)` calls to your `forEach` loop?

Comment: @jibsales No, because the length of the string can differ.

Comment: @jibsales Or maybe I can check the length and add writeInt16(0) for each missing bytes to complete it?

Comment: or instead of `packet.writeStringNT()` you could use `packet.writeString(value, [offset])`

Comment: @jibsales but how would that add the padding?

Comment: @jibsales here they have array padding: http://bigeasy.github.io/packet/
but I just cant make it work to create a buffer, only parse. Any idea how to build a buffer with that package?

Comment: In all honesty, I use substack's `put` module for binary data handling: https://github.com/substack/node-put

Comment: @jibsales not too documented :(

Comment: True, but you don't need it with how thin the code is — take a gander at the tests and `index.js` and that is all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart-Buffer keeps track of its position for you so you do not need to specify an offset to know where to insert the data to pad your string. You could do something like this with your existing code:

```
channels.forEach(function (key){
    console.log(key);
    packet.writeString(key);   // This is the string with no padding added.
    packet.writeUInt32BE(0);   // Four 0x00's are added after the string itself.
});
```

I'm assuming you want:  42 4C 41 5A 45 00 00 00 00 42 4C 41 5A 45 00 00 00 00  etc.

Editing based on comments:

There is no built in way to do what you want, but you could do something like this:

```
channels.forEach(function (key){
    console.log(key);
    packet.writeString(key); 
    for(var i = 0; i <= (9 - key.length); i++)
        packet.writeInt8(0);
});
```

Comment: Yes but what if the key is 8 characters long? which should leave only one 00. The string is based on a configuration. limited to 8 characters long. like, `42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 00`